# Given a church encoded numeral as closure result from a CEK-machine, how to get back the number?

Tags: haskell, closures, church-encoding

I have implemented the CEK-machine. Given a closure result from this algorithm and the knowledge that this closure is a Church-encoded numeral, what is the best way to print out the numeral?

Using the following types:

```hs
data Term = Var String | Abs String Term | App Term Term
data Clos = Clos String Term Env
type Env = [(String, Clos)]
```

EDIT:
To make this vague question a little clearer:
Starting my machine with `(\n f x -> f (n f x)) (\f x -> x)` (`s z`) I end up with:

```hs
(\f -> (\x -> (f ((n f) x)))) :: Term
[("n", Clos((\f -> (\x -> x)), []))] :: Env
```

This is a datastructure that represents a closure that represents a church numeral. How can I reify this structure to a number? Do I have to walk through the environment of the closure and substitute the variables in the `Term` (sounds inefficient)? Do I need renaming for this?

EDIT:
Actual code:

```hs
data Term = Var String | Abs String Term | App Term Term deriving (Show)
data Clos = Clos String Term Env deriving (Show)
type Env = [(String, Clos)]
data Frame = FArg Term Env | FFun Clos deriving (Show)
data State = State Term Env [Frame] deriving (Show)

step :: State -> Maybe State
step (State (Var x) env k) = fmap (\(Clos y b env') -> State (Abs y b) env' k) $ lookup x env
step (State (App a b) env k) = return $ State a env (FArg b env : k)
step (State (Abs x b) env (FArg t env' : k)) = return $ State t env' (FFun (Clos x b env) : k)
step (State (Abs x b) env (FFun (Clos y b' env') : k)) = return $ State b' ((y, Clos x b env) : env') k
step _ = Nothing

steps :: State -> State
steps st = maybe st steps (step st)

z = Abs "f" $ Abs "x" $ Var "x"
s = Abs "n" $ Abs "f" $ Abs "x" $ App (Var "f") $ App (App (Var "n") (Var "f")) (Var "x")
term = App s z
result = steps $ State term [] []
main = putStrLn $ show result
```

Results in:

```hs
State (Abs "f" (Abs "x" (App (Var "f") (App (App (Var "n") (Var "f")) (Var "x"))))) [("n",Clos "f" (Abs "x" (Var "x")) [])] []
```

Comment: Under those assumptions, count the number of the `App`s inside the term.

Comment: @chi, I don't think that works, unless you assume reduction under lambdas. See also Daniel Wagner's comment.

Comment: @dfeuer Correct, I was assuming to have a numeral in normal form.

Comment: " (sounds inefficient)" ;-) a Church encoding just _is_ inefficient. It's to demonstrate the power of the lambda calculus, not intended for any serious computation. You need an `Eval` or `Interp` function that pulls the variables' assignments out of the `Env` and executes them.

Comment: I guess what you're discovering here is part of the motivation for including base types that are not lambdas -- since functions are so difficult to (correctly) introspect on, you include some types that are easier to inspect!

Comment: Yeah I have come to the same conclusion. I am working on a little toy language based on pure lambda calculus, but it's not much fun computing stuff if you can't see the result :p So I will have to add some stuff to the CEK machine. Thanks everyone for the help anyway.

Answer (score 3):

A Church numeral is a function of two arguments

```
type Church a = (a -> a) -> a -> a
```

The second argument is the zero case, the first argument is the increment case. So you just need to apply the numeral to a suitable couple of arguments to get some (typically numeric) data type:

```
fromChurch c = c (+ 1) (0 :: Int)
```

Comment: Your `fromChurch` works on an Haskell function, while my `c` is of type `Clos` so I cannot apply it.

Comment: I updated my question. @DanielWagner I think the issue I have here is the "fully applying and reducing" because the term I get out from the CEK-machine is an abstraction with free variables together with an environment that assigns closures to those variables. I will not end up with a term of the form `\s z -> s ... s z).